# Connection cuts serveing files with mod_wsgi

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi

i am runing an apache 2.2 server on linux. using mod_wsgi to serve http with python code.

when trying to serve a large file it stops at about 95% without rasing an exception on the server.

curl shows this error:

> curl: (18) transfer closed with 160800 bytes remaining to read

the code:

> if 'wsgi.file_wrapper' in environ:

```
    self.body = environ['wsgi.file_wrapper'](self.file, block_size)
else:
    self.body = iter(lambda: self.file.read(block_size), '')
```

when runing the same code in windows all is working.

what could be the problem?

Comment: For curl to give a message like that, it must have been presented a Content-Length for the response, how are you setting that? Are you perhaps on Windows and using file size, which will be wrong if has CRLF and you open file in text mode, which results in CR being suppressed in data sent back. Ensure you open files in raw mode.

Comment: the Content-Length is set by `size = os.path.getsize(self.path)`.
and file opend with "rb" flag